# why is the benefit(s) of using the set command in the following code?

Tags: python-3.x

In the following code, there are no duplicates that means I cannot see why the set command is used.

Code:

```
def isPalindrome(word):

    return word == word[::-1]

def getPalindromesFromStr(inputStr):

    cleanStr = inputStr.replace(",","").lower()
    words = set(cleanStr.split(" "))
    wPalindromes = [word for word in words if isPalindrome(word) and word != "" ]
    return wPalindromes

print(getPalindromesFromStr("Lol, this is a gag, I didn’t laugh so much in a long time"))
```

Comment: It's a function which means the use case you see here is probably not going to be the only use case you ever see.

Comment: Is that your code? Where did you get it from? Does the source say this function is intended *only* for the single input shown?

Comment: No is it not my code I got it online. The question is:  Question: identity all words that are palindromes in the following sentence “Lol, this is a gag, I didn’t laugh so much in a long time”. I want to understand each line of code but cannot see the porpose of moving the list to the set.  There was no other infomation to help you answering my question.

Comment: It's generally not sensible to analyse a function only for a single input. Otherwise, the most effective implementation would just use ``return ['gag', 'i', 'a', 'lol']``.